# Can't put div near controll that showing next divs

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Thanks everyone for helping me, that I get this piece of code, but I need more.

When page is downloaded piece of div is hidden, but when I click on image it shows,

BUT: I want to write some text near that image and put in some tag,but it crashes all.

My code in view:

```
  <% @websites.each do |website| %>
   <div class="sub">
<%= link_to(image_tag("/images/caret-horizontal.png", id: "caret-horizontal"), '#') %>
     <%= website.name %>//when I put this in tag show doesn't work
     <div class="desc">
       <%= website.url %> 
   <%= website.category %> 
    <%= website.language %>
   </div>
    </div>
         <% end %>
```

My javascript:

```
 $(".sub a").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div").show("medium");
});
```

Can someone correct me or explain how to do it ?

Comment: What's the error message? (Use firebug or other to see it)

Comment: I mean it doesn't show and stay hidden.

Comment: I think in my misunderstanding jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put some tag next to link before the div the `next()` wont work right??

Documentation:

```
Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.
```

Use `.siblings()` instead of `next()`...that will work...